# PHP Multi Dimensional Array Intersect with Unidimensional

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Need to eliminate from Array A arrays that key 'service_code' value doesn't exist on Array B. In the example, only 'SAF' exists on Array B. Have tried a variety of array_intersect functions with no luck. Instead of doing a loop, I believe there must be a method unknown to me to accomplish this. I can also invert Array B by removing array_keys if necessary.

**Array A**

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [service_name] => Carpet Cleaning
            [type] => 
            [category_name] => Household
            [service_code] => SAF
            [category_code] => AA
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [service_name] => Floor Cleaning
            [type] => 
            [category_name] => Household
            [service_code] => MHSAF
            [category_code] => AA
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [service_name] => Lawn Service
            [type] => 
            [category_name] => Landscape
            [service_code] => GHF
            [category_code] => AA
        )
)
```

**Array B**

```
Array
(
    [0] => SAF
    [1] => SA
    [2] => MM
    [3] => METH
    [4] => OTPA
    [5] => OTP
    [6] => CBT
    [7] => SACA
    [8] => TRC
    [9] => REBT
)
```

**Expected Result**

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [service_name] => Carpet Cleaning
            [type] => 
            [category_name] => Household
            [service_code] => SAF
            [category_code] => AA
        )
)
```

Comment: Is `service_code` unique in array A, or can multiple entries have the same one?

Comment: yes, service_code unique in array A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end of the day you will doing loops no matter what with those data structures, even if the "loop" is hidden within a function call like `array_filter()`.

My number one suggestion would be to change Array B if possible so that you don't need to iterate it to see if a value in the array exists.  A data structure like:

```
[
  'SAF' => 1,
  'SA' => 1,
   ...
]
```

You can achieve a data structure like this easily be executing `array_flip()` on the array.

A structure where the keys contain the values you are looking for will let you do an O(1) lookup - instead of O(n) - for checking service codes from array A.

Your code could then look like:

```
$result = array_filter($array_a, function($item, $k) use ($array_b) {
    return array_key_exists($item['service_code'], $array_b);   
});
```

If you cannot change array b as described you would need to iterate Array B (which is what happens when you call `in_array()` function) in the `array_filter` operation:

```
$result = array_filter($array_a, function($item, $k) use ($array_b) {
    return in_array($item['service_code'], $array_b);  
});
```

The first solution would have a run time complexity of O(n) where n is number of elements in Array A.

The second solution would have a run time complexity of O(n*m) where m is number of elements of Array B (n is still number of elements in array A).

Since the second solution performs so poorly, you can optimize by using `array_flip()`

```
$service_code_keys = array_flip($array_b);
$result = array_filter(
    $array_a,
    function($item, $k) use ($service_code_keys) {
        return array_key_exists($item['service_code'], $service_code_keys); 
    }  
);
```

The would improve operational complexity to O(m + n) as you take a one time O(m) hit to iterate and flip Array B. Still this is much improved over the `in_array()` solution.

Comment: Using first solution, getting error @mike-brant ' Missing argument 2 for {closure}()'

Comment: nevermind @Mike-Brant, i remove the second param from function now works. function($item) use

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is `array_filter`:

```
$filtered = array_filter(
    $array1,
    function($v) use ($array2) {
        return in_array($v['service_code'], $array2);
    }
);
```

Comment: This solution works, but has more operational complexity than necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Because `service_code` is unique across array A, you can use `array_column` to reindex array A using `service_code`.

```
$array_a = array_column($array_a, null, 'service_code');
```

Then flip array B so that its values become keys

```
$array_b = array_flip($array_b);
```

Then you can use `array_intersect_key` to get your result.

```
$result = array_intersect_key($array_a, $array_b);
```

Or all in one statement if you like:

```
$result = array_intersect_key(
    array_column($array_a, null, 'service_code'), array_flip($array_b));
```

Comment: That won't generate desired output, which contains the entire inner array element for successful intersections.

Comment: Apologies, I misread the code. This solution will work, but is not very optimal from a complexity standpoint.  Each inner function call would be O(n) and the outer would be O(n + m) Ibelieve